# Preferred File Location for Static Files in Maven WAR Project

Tags: java, maven, servlets

I am trying to access some WSDLs and XMLs files from WebApp which i built in Maven as a WAR. Now I knew that the `resources` folder was the default location for these types of files, but when I checked the war package, I found that the files ended up inside the `/WEB-INF` folder, which is of not much use. Just wanted to know where do I put these files so that I can access them via URL:

```
https://server:port/Context/File_Path
```

I tried to make a folder inside webapp but outside WEB-INF, it did seem to do the trick. But just wanted to know if that the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven has a concept of [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

So, yes, in order to work with something that can be packaged into WAR with maven-war-plugin you should follow the convention and place the files into the relevant folders (of course you can change these defaults if you wish).

When it comes to the static resources, indeed there is a special `src/main/webapp` folder. So you're right